# Svg figures - need scale and translate, differents between Chrome and Firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, svg

I've got svg diagram with some yellow points(circles).

```
<html>
<title>Yellow circles</title>
<body>
    <svg version="1.1" id="Слой_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
    x="0px" y="0px" width="622.4px" height="373px" viewBox="0 0 622.4 373" enable-background="new 0 0 622.4 373" xml:space="preserve">
        <polygon points="0.1,0 622.4,0 622.4,373 0.1,373 "/>
        <polygon fill="#3F3F3F" points="97,51.6 586.2,51.6 586.2,295.5 97,295.5 "/>
        <g transform="translate(342,1098.55)" fill="yellow">
            <g transform="scale(418.2,-405.9)">
                <circle cx=".2888" cy="2.0004" r=".004"></circle>
                <circle cx="-.2666" cy="2.0233" r=".004"></circle>
                <circle cx="0" cy="2.2727" r=".004"></circle>
                <circle cx="-.5845" cy="2.3201" r=".004"></circle>
                <circle cx="0" cy="2.5786" r=".004"></circle>
                <circle cx=".5845" cy="2.3201" r=".004"></circle>
            </g>
        </g>
    </svg>
</body>
```

The problem is that I can't see yellow circles using Firefox from 3 / 10 of machines(in most cases circles are displayed in Firefox)
[image]
Noticed, that yellow points displayed always by using any version of Chrome
[image]

Comment: What is common about the three machines that don't work?  Are they running they same version of FF?

Comment: I believe that FF has (used to have?) a different `transform-origin` definition from some browsers. If the machines are all running FF then the versions would be the first place I'd start.

Comment: Interesting.  I am getting it to.  It seems like it is likely a FF bug.  If you increase the circle radiuses to 0.07, they appear.  But they disappear again at 0.06.

Comment: I've reported this to FF. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1143303

Comment: They running the same last version of FF, solution "If you increase the circle radiuses to 0.07, they appear" was useful. Thanks a lot ! Hopefully to fix the bug, or other solution to this problem. Still actual to reduce the radius to 0.04

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem and found the reported bug on Firefox. Before the [update](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/rev/49341c568afe) is released (version 42), working workaround for me is to use ellipse instead of circle, e. g.:

```
<ellipse cx=".2888" cy="2.0004" rx=".004" ry=".004"></ellipse>
```